# rspec double can't be created within a before all block

Tags: ruby, rspec

This is very weird.  The following code:

```
describe "Spike" do
  before(:all) do
    something = double('name')
  end
  describe "a test" do
    it "is basic" do
      1.should == 1
    end
  end
end
```

Fails with:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `double' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x9dec5e8 @__memoized=nil>
```

./spec/unit/whatever/spike_spec.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in '

Change the `before(:all)` to `before(:each)` and everything is fine.  I'm using Ruby 1.9.3

Any ideas?

Comment: why not change `before(:all)` to `before(:each)`?  or use `let`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior, since doubles get cleaned out after every example. You should stick with using these in a `before(:each)` block.

See https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/scope

Also see https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/202 for discussion on this.

Comment: Accepted because it answers the question as written, thanks. I still need to find a way around it...will post a new question.

Comment: @Stefan is there a specific reason it **must** be in an `:all` block?

Comment: Yes, see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175823/how-to-stub-out-unwanted-static-function-in-rspec-examples