# How to stub out global logging function in rspec examples

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, code-cleanup

I am working with some code which logs to a global static logging class, e.g.:

```
GlobalLog.debug("Some message")
```

However in my tests, I don't want to include the real log, because it introduces a lot of unwanted dependencies.  So I want to mock it out:

```
describe "some function" do
  before(:all) do
    log = double('log')
    GlobalLog = log
    log.stub(:debug)
  end
  ...
end
```

Unfortunately, because doubles are cleared out after each example, this isn't allowed:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/scope

If I change the `before(:all)` to `before(:each)`, the code works, but I get a warning:

```
warning: already initialized constant GlobalLog
```

This is clogging up my test output, so I'd like to avoid the warning.  Is there a clean solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `GlobalLog` once in your `spec_helper.rb`.

```
class GlobalLog
  class << self
    [:info, :debug, :warn, :error].each do |method|
      define_method(method) {|*|}
    end
  end
end
```

You could throw it in `spec/support` if you want to be cleaner about it.

Comment: I had to modify to take arguments: `define_method(method) { |*args|}`, but it basically works!

Answer (score 1):

Why won't you stub original `GlobalLog` object method?

```
before(:each)
  GlobalLog.stub(:debug)
end
```

Comment: Where do you have your `GlobalLog` class defined?

Comment: I don't know, and I specifically don't want to know :-).  It's a dependency buried within some code that I don't want to care about, since it's not relevant to the tests I'm writing at the moment.  That's why I had hoped to just stub it out.